# Text selection and display in context menu chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on a small Chrome extension with a problem I cant seem to get my head around and would appreciate someone to look at it with a fresh perspective.

The goal is to create a chrome extension which enables you to select text on any given website and displays an option to send the selection to another website using a contextmenu item.

My **manifest.json** looks like this:

```
{
"name": "Context Menu Search",
"description": "Opens the selected text as keyword in a new window",
"version": "0.1",
"permissions": ["contextMenus"],
"background_page": "background.html"
}
```

Then **background.html**:

```
<script src="rightclick.js"></script>
```

And **rightclick.js**:

```
var selection_callbacks = []; 
 function getSelection(callback) { 
 selection_callbacks.push(callback); 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file:"selection.js" }); 
  }; 
  chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request) { 
    var callback = selection_callbacks.shift(); 
    callback(request); 
  });

function sendSearch(selectedText) {
var serviceCall = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + selectedText;
chrome.tabs.create({url: serviceCall});
}
var tx = getSelection();
var title = "Test '" + tx + "' menu item";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[selection],
                                   "onclick": sendSearch(tx)});
console.log("selection item:" + id);
```

Plus **selection.js**:

```
chrome.extension.sendResponse(window.getSelection().toString());
```

So far the context menu creation works fine, but the selected text is not displayed at all.
If anyone has any suggestions on how to solve this problem as well as simplify the script, I would appreciate your input.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I just looked at the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create) and all this can be done much more simpler without any content scripts and callbacks:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Test %s menu item", 
    contexts:["selection"], 
    onclick: function(info, tab) {
        sendSearch(info.selectionText);
    }
});
```

That's all you need, because you can use `%s` in menu title to get selected text.

*(everything below is not needed anymore)*

---

Your `getSelection()` method doesn't return selected text, it just injects a content script to a page. Selected text is received sometime later in `onRequest` and then passed to a callback function from your callback array as a parameter.

So  this part:

```
var tx = getSelection();
var title = "Test '" + tx + "' menu item";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[selection],
                                   "onclick": sendSearch(tx)});
console.log("selection item:" + id);
```

needs to be changed to something like this:

```
getSelection(function(tx) { 
    var title = "Test '" + tx + "' menu item";
    var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":["selection"],
                                       "onclick": sendSearch(tx)});
    console.log("selection item:" + id);
})
```

But I would get rid of that `selection_callbacks` array altogether as I think it is not needed:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request) { 
    var tx = request;
    var title = "Test '" + tx + "' menu item";
    var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":["selection"],
                                       "onclick": sendSearch(tx)});
    console.log("selection item:" + id);
});
```

Also note that `"contexts":[selection]` needs to be `"contexts":["selection"]`, and `"onclick": sendSearch(tx)` needs to be something like this instead:

```
"onclick": function(info, tab) {
    sendSearch(info.selectionText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer serg, you left the %s out in the code part of your answer, but I got it working with your suggestion!

Comment: Is it possible to get the selected text as line by line content with new line characters ?

Comment: And it can even be a little shorter. The [example page on contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contextmenus) shows ``chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context], "onclick": genericOnClick});``, so without explicitly passing the ``info`` and ``tab`` parameters and creating an anonymous function that calls a named function. Your example will become: ``chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Test %s menu item", contexts:["selection"], onclick: sendSearch(info.selectionText);}});`` when ``sendSearch``'s first argument is ``info``.