# Selection type changes context menu using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension. In it I want the context menu to change according to the selected text on the page.

For example, if its a number I want a menu that says divisibility test for this numbr is ...
and if it is a string, it should have a something else, but not both at the same time.

I cant figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set a listener for mouse down. There is no other way to get the selected text before the menu is created.

See this SO question:

[chrome extension context menus, how to display a menu item only when there is no selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382467/chrome-extension-context-menus-how-to-display-a-menu-item-only-when-there-is-no)

Here is part of the code the rest is at the link.

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
//right click
if(event.button == 2) {
    if(window.getSelection().toString()) {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "createSelectionMenu"});
    } else {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "createRegularMenu"});
    }
  }
}, true);
```

Comment: Huh. here is another SO question with a little bit different solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376167/text-selection-and-display-in-context-menu-chrome-extension