# Render context menu depending on selection

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to display a different menu option depending on whether a number or text is selected.

I've tried playing with content scripts but I can't get them to work in gmail which is where I need it to work. Here is what I have, it works on sites other than gmail (is it a https thing?)

**Background.html**

`<script src="driver.js"></script>`

**content_script.js**

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
  if(event.button == 2) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: selection});
  }

}, true);
```

**driver.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
    alert(request.cmd);
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Context Menu Search",
"description": "Opens the selected text as keyword in a new window",
"version": "0.1",
"permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
"background_page": "background.html"
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382467/chrome-extension-context-menus-how-to-display-a-menu-item-only-when-there-is-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selection type changes context menu using chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808572/selection-type-changes-context-menu-using-chrome-extension/6810043#6810043)

You will have to set a listener for mouse down. There is no other way to get the selected text before the menu is created.

See this SO question:

[chrome extension context menus, how to display a menu item only when there is no selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382467/chrome-extension-context-menus-how-to-display-a-menu-item-only-when-there-is-no)

Here is part of the code the rest is at the link.

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
//right click
if(event.button == 2) {
    if(window.getSelection().toString()) {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "createSelectionMenu"});
    } else {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "createRegularMenu"});
    }
   }
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've had a play and got that working. However it won't work on https sites. I'm writing this extension for use in my gmail account. I've added the following to my manifest file.

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],

Comment: Got it working, I found that setting "all_frames" to true in my manifest file let it start working in Gmail.

"permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],

Comment: Great! I apologize I didn't get notified that you'd posted any comments.