# Chrome Extension - change the text in text field by context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write my first Chrome extension. I want to be able to select text with the mouse in text field in website and by clicking on context menu to change this text.

Here's the eventPage.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData) {
  if (clickData.menuItemId === "change" && clickData.selectionText) {

  }
});
```

Here's the manifest.json:

```
"background": {
"scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
"persistent": false
},

"permissions": ["contextMenus"]
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Comment: Can you clarify   _I want to be able to mark text in text field_  ?

Comment: @abdulla_malik is correct, we can't help you until you provide more information. It's a little unclear what you mean by "marking text".

Comment: You'll need to run a content script code in the web page process e.g. by using chrome.tabs.executeScript, that script may use document.execCommand with 'insertText' parameter and your text.

Answer (score -1):

It says you are new to StackOverflow. Welcome! :D

Check the link below you'll have your answer there.

[Text selection and display in context menu chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376167/text-selection-and-display-in-context-menu-chrome-extension)