# How to get selected text in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

`window.getSelection().toString()` doesn't get selected text in Chrome.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, that should be done within a content script, I explained how its done here:
[Chrome Extension: how to capture selected text and send to a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626859/chrome-extension-how-to-capture-selected-text-and-send-to-a-web-service)