# Creating A Simple Google Chrome Than On Right Clicking On Selected Text Causes Selected Text To Become Italics

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple google chrome extension which can convert selected text to italics on right clicking on the menu and selecting to italics from it.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you probably want to add "turn into italics" into the context menu that appears when the user right clicks?

In that case, you want to add an item to the context menu through this [API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html). Then, at the callback function, you get the tab id. From there, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626859/chrome-extension-how-to-capture-selected-text-and-send-to-a-web-service) to get the rest of the way through. Drop a line if you encounter any problems.