# Develop a Google Chrome extension using Google Translate

Tags: javascript, json, rest, google-chrome-extension

Hi, I am developing a Google Chrome extension:
It is a dictionary that uses the Google translate API,
When the user selects a text on the page I would like a popup to appear and show the selected text definition,

I have this code in my js file :

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
    "GET",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?" +
    "format=html" +
    "q=" + get_text_selection() + // Source Text
"source=en&" + // Source Language
"target=fa&" + // Target Language
true);
req.send(null);

function get_text_selection() {

    if (window.getSelection)

    return window.getSelection();

    if (document.getSelection)

    return document.getSelection();

    if (document.selection)

    return document.selection.createRange().text;

    return '';

}
```

and this code in my Manifest.json file :

```
{
  "name": "Google Translator",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This Extention helps you to translate text in your page",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "Dictionary-Book-icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "tabs" ]
}
```

and this code in my html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width:357px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

    </style>
    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

but it's not working?
Where is my problem?
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626859/chrome-extension-how-to-capture-selected-text-and-send-to-a-web-service. But you also need to know how to communicate between the active page and the popup. I'm sure that question has also been asked, but I can't find it at the moment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `Google Translate API` is a [paid service](https://developers.google.com/translate/) now. To use `Google Translate API` you need to get an `API key` from `Google`, you can get more information from [here](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#auth). After you get an `API key` your `url` should be like

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=fa&q=Hello%20world" // "Hello world" is query here
```

Which is in your case

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY" + "&format=html" + "&source=en" +"&target=fa" + "&q=" + get_text_selection()
```

Using following request (using my valid key from the browser address bar)

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=my_valid_key&format=html&q=home&source=en&target=fa" // I've replaced my key with my_valid_key
```

I've got this result

```
{  "error": {   "errors": [    {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"    }   ],
    "code": 403,   
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"  
  }
}
```

[Google Translate API no longer free](http://drupal.org/node/1215426) and [Translate API FAQ](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq).