# Need to get selected text as a string from the current tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Here's the code I currently have:

```
var clicked = function(){
    var selection
    chrome.tts.speak(selection, {'lang': 'en-US', 'rate': 0.8, 'enqueue': true});
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Say '%s'!",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["selection"],
  "onclick" : clicked()
});
```

I need to get the selection from the current tab. I don't know how to get it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2645306/650722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Don't call `clicked()`, but pass a function reference, by omitting the parentheses.
2. `var selection` is available from the [function's parameters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#property-createProperties-onclick). In the documentation, this object is described as [`OnClickData`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData). The desired info is stored in the `selectionText` key.

Code after applying these fixes:

```
// Background page
var clicked = function(info, tab) {
    var selection = info.selectionText;
    chrome.tts.speak(selection, {'lang': 'en-US', 'rate': 0.8, 'enqueue': true});
};
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Say '%s'!",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["selection"],
  "onclick" : clicked
});
```