# listen to selected text drag event in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my extension to listen to the event when a some text is selected (highlighted) and then dragged.
just like opening new tab with dragging url to tab box. I have seen this answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626859/chrome-extension-how-to-capture-selected-text-and-send-to-a-web-service) answer but it gets the text highlighted when icon is clicked but I want my some function foo() to fire automatically when text is selected and dragged. can any one help me please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So first, you'll want to create your handler function:

```
function highlightHandler(e) {
    // get the highlighted text
    var text = document.getSelection();
    // check if anything is actually highlighted
    if(text !== '') {
        // we've got a highlight, now do your stuff here
        doStuff(text);
    }
}
```

And then, you'll need to bind it to your document:

```
document.onmouseup = highlightHandler;
```

And finally, write your `doStuff` function to do what you want it to do:

```
function doStuff(text) {
    // do something cool
}
```

Comment: Clean code and well commented, just what I was looking for.